# Custom status using discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

This is my code

```
  activity=discord.Game(name="Padamine", type=1)
```

Don’t worry, I put it in a @bot.event function. The problem is that my bot don’t put the custom status in his status. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change_presence()` method to change bot status:

```py
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("Padamine"))
```

Comment: Well I didn't want to insult anyone but by searching `discord py playing status` the first result is the answer. If the first thing that you find doesn't work just try looking somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static status (a status that won't change), it is recommended to use the `activity` keyword argument inside the bot constructor. If you want to make a dynamic status (a status that changes every now and then), use `@tasks.loop` of `discord.ext.tasks` ([you can find more about tasks here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html))

```
# depending on what you name your variable, client/bot
client/bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="yourprefix", activity=discord.Game("Padamine")) # removed type because there is no such key word argument
```

Also, it is recommended to not use `await bot.change_presence()` inside your `on_ready` event, I am mentioning this because many people do it and it's not good:

> Discord has a high chance to completely disconnect you during the READY or GUILD_CREATE events (1006 close code) and there is nothing you can do to prevent it. As noted in the docs, on_ready is also triggered multiple times, not just once.

Basically: don't do anything in `on_ready`. (except printing that it came online obviously)